# Converting string[] to ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, casting, observablecollection

I have a `string[]`. What I'd like to do is to convert the `string[]` to `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: did you look at the ctor of ObservaBleCollection<T>? it takes an IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type cast does not work. You need to initialize [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx) with `string` array.

```
new ObservableCollection(<string array>)
```